# Facebook videos don't work

Tags: firefox, flash, facebook, firefox-extensions

Hello everybody I have ubuntu 11.10 since updated my firefox to version 10 i can't play videos through facebook but the videos work fine on youtube

Also the videos work fine on chrome ( facebook and youtube ), i tried to remove firefox and install it again and install flash plugin, but the problem persist

how can i solve that ?

Comment: Install ubuntu restricted extras

Comment: @AboobackerMk i did that and the problem still there

Comment: Have you by any chance blocked Facebook videos, using extensions like Adblock Plus? How did you remove Firefox? Did you `purge` it or just remove it?

Answer (score 3):

When you click a video link on Facebook with firefox and it doesn't work. (ie: it goes to the video but doesn't do anything.) Just re-fresh the page. It works for me.

Comment: does not work foe me

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Flash#Flash_player_not_working_on_certain_websites) is some information on troubleshooting *Flash Player not working on certain websites*. Also,If you have some add-on like adblock installed,make sure that it is not blocking Facebook videos.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in 18.04 and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035670/855910) solved it for me. I just needed to enable DRM content.

> If those streaming services use DRM, you must enable DRM in Firefox's settings: Preferences -> General -> Play DRM-controlled content

Link: https://askubuntu.com/a/1035670/855910

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
gksu nautilus /etc/adobe/mms.cfg
```

And rename the file to something else (`mms.cfg.bo`).

Restart Firefox/Chrome and your videos should be working fine.