# Playing Videos in Firefox

Tags: firefox, video, flash, html5

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and Firefox 60.0 (linux beginner!)

I just installed the flash player, but the only videos that are displayed in my browser are the ones on youtube.
facebook and any other streaming-services can not play videos.

do i need to install/enable html5 somehow?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If those streaming services use DRM, you must enable DRM in Firefox's settings: *Preferences -> General -> Play DRM-controlled content* You might also have to install package `libavcodec-extra` to get the codecs:

`sudo apt install libavcodec-extra`

Comment: works on Ubuntu 18.04.2 with Firefox 62, thanks.

Comment: works like a charm

Comment: Great!, working now.

Comment: Woks on Ubuntu 16.04LTS. Thanks

Comment: Works on 19.04, but how the hell is my grandma supposed to figure this out? We gotta do better than this...

Comment: didnt fix this in the latest version of ubuntu

Comment: you have to restart firefox after the apt install

Comment: It's not in "general", but in "content".

Comment: Used this command `sudo apt install libavcodec-extra58 libavcodec-extra`
in ubuntu-20.04. Otherwise it threw `unmet dependencies` error.