# Can't stream any online videos on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: video-streaming

So I've been using Ubuntu 18.04 for a couple of months now, it was running perfectly until one random day when I log in, and I'm unable to play ANY videos online, Firefox or Chrome. I've tried repair packages and systems check from the grub menu,and I'm currently running the 4.15.32 kernel. Any help?

Comment: did you try https://askubuntu.com/a/1035670/790920

Comment: I did. unfortunately it didnt help :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix for not being able to run HBO GO on ubuntu 18.04: you have to download the CHROME browser. Not Chromium, but the Linux version for Chrome! 
I found a tutorial on linuxize how to donwload it. You will need to use Terminal, but it is a sure fix.
So, hobgo will only stream from the official Chrome browser on ubuntu 18.04

For Netflix, you have to use FIrefox and download the libavcodec pack, also using Terminal. Also, a tutorial for this is available online.
It is my first day on ubuntu 18.04 and I find it annoying that I have to use Terminal so much for so many things. However, I find this OS generally much faster and stable than any WIndows.
Thanks to the Linux community online, most issues are easily solved and there are command lines for almost everything!

Answer (score 0):

This occurred for me on 16.04 a few days ago, updating to 18.04 did not fix it but going to 19.04 did.
No additional manual codec changes performed. Looks a change in the way chrome & ff interact with the o/s apis is not fully backwards compatible.