# Video error code 102630

Tags: 18.04, video

Every time I try and watch a movie online I get video file cannot be played, error code 102630. Can anyone tell me what I can do about this. I'm fairly new to ubuntu 18.04. Thanks

Comment: First search on Google https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/50473/this-video-file-cannot-be-played-error-code-102630.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing Videos in Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035661/playing-videos-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

If those streaming services use DRM, you must enable DRM in Firefox's settings: Preferences -> General -> Play DRM-controlled content You might also have to install package libavcodec-extra to get the codecs:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one option is downgrade the firefox browser. Perform this command on your terminal.

```
apt-cache show firefox | grep Version
```

You'll see something like this

```
Version: 87.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
Version: 75.0+build3-0ubuntu1
```

Now it's time to rollback

```
sudo apt-get install firefox=75.0+build3-0ubuntu1
```

Done, good luck.